# How can I determine the CODECS value for a m3u8 playlist?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am creating a master m3u8 file to allow adaptive streaming of two streaming videos. Both have the readable codec name MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)

How can I translate this into the CODECS value that should appear in my master m3u8 playlist file, as in this example:

`#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1755600,CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=354x240`

How do I get the value to replace `avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2`

Apple's specs say "Valid format identifiers are those in the ISO file format name space defined by RFC 6381 [RFC6381]" but I have no idea how to read the RFC 6381 documentation.

Comment: RFC6381 mentions a registry:  http://mp4ra.org/#/codecs  There's a more specific list somewhere... if I can find it, I'll come back and post here.

Comment: Thanks for your help. With advice here, I found a utility that gave me the info I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Each codec string is codec specific. For audio, `mp4a` indicate its mpeg audio `40` means its mpeg 4.0 (I think) and the last integer is the "audio object type". AAC-LC is 2. The full list can be found here. https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/MPEG-4_Audio#Audio_Object_Types

For video, in your example case, The video codec is h.264, also known as "advanced video codec"  aka `avc1`. The hex string is 3 bytes representing the codec profile, flags, and level. Those can be found in the first 3 bytes the the SPS.

Other codecs are different.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With advice from commenters here, I refined my Google searches and eventually found a blog post explaining how the codes are constructed:

A comment on this post led me to the mp4box.js utility, which loads a file and gives a ton of info, including the CODECS value:

[image: mp4box.js info showing CODECS]

Answer (score 0):

You can consult ffmpeg code https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/blob/HEAD:/libavformat/hlsenc.c , search for 'write_codec_attr' (but unfortunately it is not in any public interface)